# Cómo corregir este error al ejecutar xampserver?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, localhost, wampserver

Al ejecutar Xamppserver, veo este error:

> The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 27:[EParseError] Unrecognized parameter name "WAMPMARIADBOFFName";

Intenté buscar en youtube como arreglarlo y en google y no encontré ayuda

Comment: Y cómo esta configurado?

Answer (score -1):

WAMPPServer es medio especial, trata lo siguiente

1. Elimina la instalación
2. Instala todas las dependencias del VC++
3. Reinstala WAMPP como administrador

Nos avisas

Saludos

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. A lo más sería un comentario. Espera a tener la reputación suficiente.